# sqlite3 OperationalError: no such column (python)

Tags: python, sqlite, operationalerror

this is my code

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Blockchain_address SET money_of_address = ? WHERE address = temp_2", (temp_amount,))
```

it returns the error

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: temp_2
```

indeed there is no column temp_2 but temp_2 is a variable. and I would like to look in my DB for where the column money_of_address has the value temp_2. What should I do?

Comment: if `temp_2` is a variable, why not use a second `?`parameter ?

Comment: like "WHERE address = ?", (temp_amount, temp_2)